# Where is Liferay taglib documentation?

Tags: documentation, liferay-6, taglib

I'm looking for the taglib documentation of Liferay. I've found http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/taglibs/ but each and every entry I clicked so far is empty except the automatically generated type info.

So, how do I find out which purpose a tag in Liferay fulfills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check details over http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/discussion-tag-libra-2 ,also you can go through Liferay in Action book chapter 4, contain a brief description about the liferay taglibs.

Comment: The link directed me to the main page. A similar link is http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/discussion-tag-libra-1 but I can't see how this would relate to the question. The book is ok as a general overview but its no reference.

Comment: Detail description for the taglibs are not avilable,but for the reference purpose you can check http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/reference,may be it's helpful ,also over liferay.com detail description is not given for all the taglibs, but ui taglib is available i.e. http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/UI+Taglib

Comment: Essentially there is no full reference documentation for the taglibs. Some help can be found in the wiki.